# netbook alternate installation/update

Tags: alternative, usb-installation

I have an Asipre One D255E netbook.

Installed 9.10 sucessfully, but no internet connections to upgrade to 10.04 or 10.10.

Have 10.10 alternate (couldnt get 10.04). However it says that no cd-rom present (netbook via live usb), and I directed it to sdb1 but that did not work.

Could someone guide me to the steps to installation via alternate USB only (& no internet)?

The live usb's of 10.04 & 10.10 internet connections worked, but installation hanged (non alternate).

Thank you greatly in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the Upgrade Notes [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes). It is recommended that you upgrade from progressive versions or LTS releases only.

Try and install via the method outlined by UbuntuGeek [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-ubuntukubuntuedubuntuxubuntu-without-cdrom-drive.html) and let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you will try these tomorrow, and will be sure to post back on how i do.

Comment: trying alternate 10.04 install but so far hanging at 45% of 'starting up the partitioner' scanning disks...
:S